# Mounting non-usb devices on Virtualbox VM

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tuner-card

I have Windows 7 running on bare metal. I have a Haupage TV tuner card installed on there that Win 7 detects and runs smoothly.

I have now installed Vitualbox on Win7, and created a Ubuntu VM. I would like to mount that tuner card to that VM.

Vitualbox lets you map USB devices to VMs, but not any other non-USB devices. Can this be done ? Are there other Hypervisors out there that let you do this?

EDIT 1 - My virtualbox setup already has extensions installed. 
EDIT 2 - The device i would like to map to the VM is a Hauppauge WinTV-HVR-2250 PCI Card mounted on PCI Bus (got that info from Device manager in Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by a non-USB device you mean  PCI or PCIExpress device.

VirtualBox has [experimental support](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) for PCI passthrough via an extension.  However, support is only available on Linux hosts and only with certain hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, [install Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). You can download the version-specific one on the VirtualBox website.

Which non-USB devices you want to mount?

Comment: I have added name and type of device to my question. Please check above.